# Is it possible to create more than one statement in lambda functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

We were tasked to create a lambda function for sorting a list of floating-point numbers by the value of the first decimal digit. The elements with the same first decimal digit must be sorted in increasing order.

For example:

```
l = [45.2133, 80.7795, 2.3048, 50.2441, 16.1436, 53.6323, 21.742, 15.9621, 46.0865, 58.7235]
l.sort(key=f1)
print(l)
```

Output must be

```
[46.0865, 16.1436, 45.2133, 50.2441, 2.3048, 53.6323, 21.742, 58.7235, 80.7795, 15.9621]
```

I have tried the lambda function below:

```
f1 = lambda x: x - int(x)
```

however it doesn't sort in increasing order the numbers with the same first decimal digit and we can't use functions, only modules.

Comment: I don't know what "we can't use functions, only modules" means. But that code *does* sort by the first decimal digit, so it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: The code you gave correctly sorts numbers by the part after the decimal point. The only numbers not in the order you gave are 21.742 and 58.7235, which sort with `.7235` before `.742`.

Comment: Beside the point, but a named lambda is bad practice. Lambdas are supposed to be anonymous. Write a `def` instead. Per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations), *"Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier."* BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

You can use following `lambda` as key to `sort`:

```
lambda x: (int(str(x).split('.')[1][0]), x)
```

**Code**:

```
l = [45.2133, 80.7795, 2.3048, 50.2441, 16.1436, 53.6323, 21.742, 15.9621, 46.0865, 58.7235]

l.sort(key=lambda x: (int(str(x).split('.')[1][0]), x))
print(l)

# [46.0865, 16.1436, 45.2133, 50.2441, 2.3048, 53.6323, 21.742, 58.7235, 80.7795, 15.9621]
```

which sorts by first decimal digit and by the value in case of a tie.

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your issue, Without having to convert X's type.

```
l = [45.2133, 80.7795, 2.3048, 50.2441, 16.1436, 53.6323, 21.742, 15.9621, 46.0865, 58.7235]

l.sort(key=lambda x: ((x % 1), x))
print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import floor

f1 = lambda x: (math.floor((x - math.floor(x)) * 10),x)
```

Credits to a friend of mine for the computational suggestion.